# Is IE9 really faster in small resolution?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I tried many website with IE9. one strange thing I found is, when I Restore Down my IE9 window and resize it to around 1000*800 or so, IE9 works pretty much faster than in Maximized mode, say around 2x faster in some times. Is there any reason behind this?

Comment: The scenario you're measuring is very relevant. If you're running a graphics demo from the IE test drive, for instance, you should be aware that some video cards have very small video buffer limits, and larger display areas exceed those limits and fall back to much slower processing.

Comment: Would this be the case for other browsers too? I don't see much difference on other browser specific to this scenario. But, glad to know the reason. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is, in your configuration, according to the benchmark you have performed.

What is it that you're asking?

If it's about "Why?", then perhaps it finds drawing the page to screen fairly slow, it's anyone's guess, really, you'd have to ask someone who works on the component in Microsoft.

Comment: @Mehrdad: In that case, it could really be anything, how can this question be improved? (I think it should be edited or clarified?)